# SQL database design employee timesheet

Tags: sql, database-design

I was wondering if someone can show/tell me the best way to store employee work hours, per day, in a database?

At the moment I have been thinking of a `TimeSheet` table {`timesheetID, employeeID, date, starttime, endtime` } but that could cause the table to grow really quickly?

I could make so it only stores 3 months worth of entries and move the rest to an archive table or simply delete the others? (Bad practices probably). So I was wondering if someone could explain to me another way of managing employee timesheets in a database.

Comment: I'd suggest recording hours worked as a pair of DATETIME values, or as a DATETIME and a duration in hours.  If you only record "date", "starttime" and "endtime", it will be awkward to compute hours worked for the poor employee whose shift ends after midnight.

Comment: How many employees would you have?? Given 1'000 employees, working 200 days per year, and adding 5 entries per day - you're looking at a million rows in that table - per year. That's **nothing** for any decent relational database system! A million **per day** might be a bit of a challenge.....

Answer (score 1):

your approach is good.

do not prematurely optimize.

indexes will be very helpful when it comes time to query.

Answer (score 0):

Depends slightly on the technology you are using, and a little more upon your anticipated volume.

Modern RDMS's are purpose-built to manage thousands, hundreds of thousands, millions of records. If you design and index your tables properly you likley have a long ways to go before you have any concerns at all.

You choice of technologies will depend on how large your company is. If this is for a small operation, the growth of your table is a minimal concern, and in fact your HR dept. may have a record-retention policy which mandates archiving, warehousing, or deletion of electronnic records after a certain period anyway.